# Power Apps, Global Objects/Control

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

New to Power Apps, I have an image of the company logo in one of my apps. I want to feature the logo in each of the screens. However, it seems I can do this only by copy-pasting the object into every screen. But this creates multiple instances of the same object, which is difficult for editing.

There should be a way to create global objects that feature in the same manner every time they are used in a screen. For example, when using shapes for design.

Am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerApps uses components to create reusable elements. Updating a component will also update all its instances throughout screens in your app.

[Shane Young explains it in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqZkUQ78e50).

Also, taking the same logic a step further, you can also define components in Component Libraries. This makes components reusable and managable in multiple apps.